# Detect Ovals or Ellipses in Python with OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am playing a sports called "Stockschiessen" in Austria. Its similar to curling. Now I came to that thought of automating the detection of the winner. So I started coding something with opencv in python. It ends up in a big problem. I can detect Circles but the "Stocks" won't be directly under the camera so I have to detect ellipses or ovals. I tried a lot but found no solution. So I just need a solution to detect these and after that I am able to calculate the distances of each "Stock".

The last Code I tried was from Geeks for Geeks:

```
import numpy as np

# Load image
image = cv2.imread('C://gfg//images//blobs.jpg', 0)

# Set our filtering parameters
# Initialize parameter settiing using cv2.SimpleBlobDetector
params = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()

# Set Area filtering parameters
params.filterByArea = True
params.minArea = 100

# Set Circularity filtering parameters
params.filterByCircularity = True
params.minCircularity = 0.9

# Set Convexity filtering parameters
params.filterByConvexity = True
params.minConvexity = 0.2
    
# Set inertia filtering parameters
params.filterByInertia = True
params.minInertiaRatio = 0.01

# Create a detector with the parameters
detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(params)
    
# Detect blobs
keypoints = detector.detect(image)

# Draw blobs on our image as red circles
blank = np.zeros((1, 1))
blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(image, keypoints, blank, (0, 0, 255),
                        cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)

number_of_blobs = len(keypoints)
text = "Number of Circular Blobs: " + str(len(keypoints))
cv2.putText(blobs, text, (20, 550),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 100, 255), 2)

# Show blobs
cv2.imshow("Filtering Circular Blobs Only", blobs)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And this is an example image, one with the "Stocks" directly under the camera and the second one is a bit disturbed. It should find the ellipses on the second image.

[Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiYsH.jpg)

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCa6o.png)

Edit:
Here are these two pictures with grayscale and thresh. I think the circles can be seen well.

[BlackAndWhite of Example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTgcT.png)

[BlackAndWhite of Example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J482q.png)

Comment: Perhaps your circularity constraint is too tight for the second image ellipses.

Comment: Tried to set it down to 0.0 as well. It detects some random circles but not the "Stocks".

Comment: investigate that blob detector, what it does to the picture. do that manually. convert picture to grayscale, then threshold it given various thresholds. can your eyes still see the ellipses?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I have done it and i can see the circles and ellipses. Have a look at the edit I have done on the question

Comment: yeah no, that won't do. you see specular reflections on the objects' curved surfaces but you don't see (you need to see) the objects themselves as solid blobs. -- many ways to skin this cat. if the background were black/white/gray, that would make things a lot easier. as it is, everything has color, and the *handles* are obstacles because they aren't the same color as the dishes (?). the simple blob detector won't help here at all because it always thresholds the input. you could cvtColor to HSL, then median-blur the hue channel, and then... some clustering

Comment: `houghCircles` should find something in the straight image. try it. probably easier. than what I suggested in the previous comment.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes houghCircles detects something but only if its a perfect circle. It its an ellipse it doesnt work. Did you mean cvtColor to HLS or to HSV? I cant find anything about HSL

Comment: the color space is called HSL (letters in that order), related to HSV. some people call it HLS but these three letters already mean a lot of other things, specifically HTTP Live Streaming, which does cross paths with image processing sometimes